# Query order by meta value force specific tag first

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, order

I have a custom post type and a shortcode to display a slider. Below is the WP_query code for the shortcode. I'm trying to order a query by tag values. I want posts with a specific tag like for example "prio" to be first in the query. So far I have this but I'm stuck.

```
$options = array(
    'post_type' => 'partner',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'post_tag',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tag' => $tag,
);
```

Comment: tags are not stored in post meta, and can't be used for ordering/sorting. What you want is not possible, you would have to order/sort the posts in PHP _after_ they've been retrieved the same way you would change the order of items in an array variable

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll look further.

Comment: think of it this way, if I have a post tagged with both `Aa` and `Zz`, should it appear first or last? And if I have a post tagged `Z last` would it come last? What if I said it had a parent tag named `A First`? It might be logical to order by tag if a post only has a single tag, but WP doesn't and can't know this, terms can be hierarchical, posts can have multiple terms, and then there's term names vs term slugs, etc, it's quite a challenge with no real solution

Answer (score 0):

This can be achievable by writing your own custom function. What you need to do is use the [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) object to do your query order by terms. When making a custom function, check your specific term id set as a parameter and then according to that remove that term id and add it back.

I have written an example code for you to understand more clearly how can you achieve that. I commented on the code so that you can understand the steps.

```
function get_term_to_start( $taxonomy = '', $args = [] ) {
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
    /*
     * Return $terms to as it is if the argument is not set or empty
     */
    if ( !isset( $args['term_to_start'] ) || empty( $args['term_to_start'] ) )
        return $terms;

    /*
     * If you have set term_to_start, then continue
     * Return $terms as it is if there is a wp error returned or if $terms is empty
     */
    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) )
        return $terms;

    /*
     * At this stage you need to convert the multidimensional objects to a multidimensional array.
     * I used json_encode and json_decode.  Now you can determine the potion of term_to_start
     */
    $terms_array = json_decode( json_encode( $terms ), true );
    $start_term_position = array_search( $args['term_to_start'], array_column( $terms_array, 'term_id'));

    /*
     * Check is $start_term_position if false, in case of failure to find the position of term_to_start
     * if false, return $terms as it is
     */
    if ( !$start_term_position )
        return $terms;

    /*
     * Get the key value pair for term_to_start, unset it from $terms and reset term_to_start pair at the 
     */
    $start_term_pair[] = $terms[$start_term_position];
    unset( $terms[$start_term_position] );
    $new_terms_array = array_merge( (array) $start_term_pair, $terms);

    /*
     * Finally you can return $new_terms_array as an object
     */
    return (object) $new_terms_array;
}

// Use above function to get list of your terms starting by your specific term id
$terms = get_term_to_start('your-taxonomy-name', array(
    'term_to_start' => 5,//YOUR SPECIFIC TERM ID. ex: id for prio is 5
));
 
// Now use the nested foreach loop along with get_posts to return your post list starting by specific term 
foreach($terms as $term){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'partner', // Your Post Type
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-name', // Your taxonomy Name. ex: tags
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term->slug
            )
        ),
        'numberposts' => -1
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($posts as $post){
        // do your stuff, posts along with your specific term will print first
    }
}
```